# How to validation from Microsoft sql sever

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, razor

My target is put an expression and validation message in this model, If it's wrong type the validation message from sql table will show on display but it has an error :

> The resource type
>   'SupplierPortal.Data.Models.MappingTable.Tbl_LocaleStringResource'
>   does not have an accessible static property named
>   '_ComPro.Addtional.CompAddtional.LblNoOfEmp'.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code

Model

SupplierPortal.Data.Models.MappingTable.Tbl_LocaleStringResource = my data message name
_ComPro.Addtional.CompAddtional.LblNoOfEmp = my data message value

```
 public partial class GeneralInfosModel
  {
     [RegularExpression("[0-9]+",ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(SupplierPortal.Data.Models.MappingTable.Tbl_LocaleStringResource),ErrorMessageResourceName="_ComPro.Addtional.CompAddtional.LblNoOfEmp")]      
       public Nullable<int> NumberOfEmp { get; set; }
  }
```

View

```
     <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group margin none">
                 <div class="form_item">
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberOfEmp, new { @class = "form-control", id = "NumberOfEmp", maxlength = "255", placeholder = "", @style = "width: 132px;" })
                 </div>
          </div>

  <div class="form-group margin-none">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.NumberOfEmp, "", new { @class = "text-danger-bold" })
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you *have* a resource with that name?

Comment: I use resource from sql table so I don't have resx file

        my resource : SupplierPortal.Data.Models.MappingTable.Tbl_LocaleStringResource

           my name value : _ComPro.Addtional.CompAddtional.LblNoOfEmp